# How to search for same search string in multiple columns?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am searching for string input from textbox control in EF data model. Could someone help me to construct the where clause in the code file to do this. 
I tried the below piece of code in the code, even though it compiles throws an error when I enter the search string and submit the search.

```
Where("it.[CaseName] like '%'" + searchString +
    "'%' or it.[CaseNumber] like '%'" + searchString +
    "'%' or it.[AppRegNumber] like '%'" + searchString +
    "'%' or it.[SSNo] like '%'" + searchString + "'%'")
```

When this same where clause was used in EntityDataSource control markup it accepts and search correctly.
I am in the process of changing my pages to use ObjectDataSource control to connect to a business logic layer class instead of directly to EDM data model.

Comment: Changed the where clause to Where("it.[CaseName] like '%" + searchString + "%'" + "or it.[CaseNumber] like '%" + searchString + "%' or it.[AppRegNumber] like '%" + searchString + "%'"). This works

Comment: BTW: Are you aware of SQL Injection? Placing a string which a user enters in a text box on a web page directly into a SQL clause is potentially very dangerous. That's the reason why the overload with `ObjectParameter` exists and is the strongly recommended way to construct a query (see my answer below). You can watch here what dangerous things are possible with SQL injection: http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer.aspx?author=keith-brown&name=aspdotnet-security&mode=live&clip=2&course=aspdotnet-security Accidentally the demo fits perfectly to your query.

Comment: @Slauma, thanks for reminding of this vulnerability. It had just slipped my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the `Where` Query Builder method of `ObjectQuery` (I think that's what you are using in your question), you need to remove the inner single quotes from the query expression:

```
Where("it.[CaseName] like '%" + searchString +
    "%' or it.[CaseNumber] like '%" + searchString +
    "%' or it.[AppRegNumber] like '%" + searchString +
    "%' or it.[SSNo] like '%" + searchString + "%'")
```

Or as a parametrized query:

```
Where("it.[CaseName] like @search" +
    " or it.[CaseNumber] like @search" +
    " or it.[AppRegNumber] like @search" +
    " or it.[SSNo] like @search",
    new ObjectParameter("search", string.Concat("%", searchString, "%")))
```

**Edit**

Don't use the first version if `searchString` comes from user input on a web page as this version is vulnerable to **SQL Injection** (enter this term in search engine for explanation). Instead use the parametrized query in the second version.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use the Linq extension methods:

```
.Where(r => r.CaseName.IndexOf(searchString) >= 0
    || r.CaseNumber.IndexOf(searchString) >= 0
    || r.AppRegNumber.IndexOf(searchString) >= 0
    || r.SSNo.IndexOf(searchString) >= 0)
```

Comment: Entered string 'sa' to search, getting the error 'sa' is not a member of type 'SCDSS_ApplicationDataModel.Applicant'

Comment: That sounds like you're turning what I wrote into a string as opposed to using System.Linq and using the method that I wrote.  You may want to read up a little bit on Linq extension methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896238.aspx

Comment: I modified my code to include what you wrote, didn't convert that to a string. In the search page entered the sa to run.